# Kafka Mirror Maker: consumer vs consumer thread number and producer number

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to point out clearly the Kafka Parallelism model for a Mirror Maker.

For what I've understood on the consumer side:

- a CONSUMER GROUP is a set of consumers. Each consumer of the group can read from one or more topic.
- a CONSUMER of the the group can have multiple streams namely the number of threads that read from the topic and the best practice is to have one thread for partition.

My doubt is: have we mutiple consumer istance with single-thread or one consumer with many threads? A consumer group refers to a set of consumers or a one multi-thread consumer?

I found difficult to point out these questions from the documentation and I would like to know if I'm wrong.

Are these consideration valids in dual way even on the producer side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The threading model in MirrorMaker (MM) is as follows:

MM deploys *N* threads.

1. Each thread instantiates and uses one consumer. That is a *1:1* mapping between MM threads and consumers.
2. Each thread shares the same producer. That is a *N:1* mapping between threads and producers.

Therefore, the number of streams you define as a property for MM (given by the value passed to `num.streams` property) corresponds to the number of MM threads and as explained above also to the number of consumers.

Now, the answer to your specific question is that this number also corresponds to the total number of threads (or streams) consuming records from your topics and partitions.

Why this holds is a bit confusing in MM because it gives you the option to use either the old high-level consumer or the new consumer. But in both cases the total number of threads consuming records is `num.streams = N` for the following reasons respectively:

1. When the old consumer high level API is used, the number of threads each consumer deploys to consume records is hardcoded by MM to 1 thread. (You may confirm this by looking at the parameters passed to the `createMessageStreamsByFilter` method in [MirrorMaker.scala](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/MirrorMaker.scala#L515)). Since one consumer is instantiated per MM thread, we end up with *N* threads consuming records.
2. In case the new consumer API is used, no threads are deployed under the covers by the consumer API to consume records (there is a heartbeat thread instantiated but that's not relevant to the discussion). Thus, here it's more straightforward that the number of threads consuming records is equal to the number of MM threads, again because MM maps one thread to each consumer it instantiates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But now I have another doubt: due to the fact that the producer map N:1 with threads, how many producers should I instantiate on the MM? For example if I have 4 target topic each one with 3 partitions it's better to have one producer. 4 producers or 12 producers?

Comment: To make sure we are on the same page, the number of producers in MM is equivalent to the number of MM java processes you instantiate (MM is fixed to use 1 producer per MM process).

Allow me first to state the obvious. The number of partitions signify a reasonable upper limit with respect to parallelism. Thus, 12 partition mean that spawning more than 12 streams (and/or 12 producers) will leave some of your streams/threads idle.

Comment: Now, regarding the parallelism that is left (here 1 to 12), the exact setup that will give you the best efficiency depends on several factors. Balance of your partitions, record size, network capacity, etc ... I haven't done exhaustive, large-scale perf eval of MM but 1 stream per MM process works adequately in many cases, and if you can't afford to deploy too many cluster nodes, several streams per producer still scales, and in general it's better than running MM with 1 producer and 1 stream for all your topics. But without knowing the specifics of your setup this is still an educated guess.